# Variable Scopes in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am working on ColdFusion scopes but I am not sure if my syntax is correct.

```
<cfset variable.siteID = #api.get('siteLookup').getsiteid(busid = 
request.businessid, orgid = org, location = Loc)#>
```

In the above line, I have converted to API calls and I have scoped it as the variable here. Is this correct? Is variable a valid ColdFusion scope?

Comment: Assuming everything to the right of the equal sign is ok, that command will create a structure named `variable` with a key named `siteID`.  That structure will be in the variables scope.

Comment: Also, nothing to do with the question, but you don't need the pound signs on the right side.

Answer (score 5):

The scope is actually `variables` (with an 's'). That is the default scope in ColdFusion. From [Learn CF in a Week - Scopes](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Scopes/):

> The following table shows major scopes available in a running ColdFusion application:
>
> - **Variables**: Default scope available in ColdFusion templates. Variables are available only during the execution of the template.
> - **URL**: All variables in the query string or sent to ColdFusion via an HTTP GET request are available in the URL scope. URL variables are available for the current request.
> - **Form**: All variables posted from a form (HTTP POST) are available in the Form scope. Form variables are available for the current request.
> - **CGI**: CGI variables sent from the browser are placed into the CGI scope. CGI variables are available for the current request.
> - **Query (not a true scope)**: Upon execution of a query, the resultset is placed into a named scope as specified by the operator assignment or cfquery tag's name attribute. The data stored in this pointer is available for the current request.
> - **Server**: Developers may choose to utilize the server scope to share data across application running within the context of the current ColdFusion instance or cluster. This scope persists across requests, and is available until the server shuts down.
> - **Application**: Application variables are shared amongst all connected clients for the current named application. This scope is also used for objects instantiated using the singleton pattern. This scope is available across requests for the life of the application, which may terminate on server shutdown, application malfunction, or application timeout.
> - **Session**: Developers use session variables to store a single visitor's data across requests. This scope is only available to the current session, and will persist until server or application termination, or session timeout.
> - **Request**: The request scope contains data that is available to all functions, CFCs, templates, and custom tags executed during the context of the current request. Data in this scope is available during the current request.
> - **Arguments**: The arguments scope contains data passed into a ColdFusion function. The arguments scope is mutually exclusive with the local function scope, and may not contain the same variable names as the local scope. This scope is available during the current execution of a function, and is private to the current function context.
> - **Attributes**: This scope contains variables passed in as attributes to a ColdFusion custom tag. The data in this scope is available during the execution lifespan of a custom tag. Refer to the ColdFusion Livedocs for additional scopes available to custom tags, as well as how scopes are handled in nested custom tags.
> - **Local (function)**: The Local scope may be referenced explicitly, or defined using the var keyword. Variables in this scope are private to the current function context. This scope is mutually exclusive with the arguments scope, and may not contain the same variable names as the arguments scope.
>
>   NOTE: The above list is not all-inclusive. Please reference the Adobe Livedocs documentation for additional and tag specific scopes.

There is more information regarding how to references these scopes in the referenced link.

Comment: This is missing the distinction between `variables` in a cfc and `variables` not in a cfc

Answer (score 0):

Your code is valid from a syntax point of view but ***`variable`*** is not a built-in ColdFusion scope.

I think you wanted this:

`<cfset variables.siteID = ...` (observe the `s` at the end)

which is equivalent of:

`<cfset siteID = ...`

which would create a variable named `siteID` in the built-in ColdFusion `variables` scope.

My point is that `<cfset variable.siteID = ...`  is either a mistake or it will create confusion in the future for you or another developer.

If you're trying to set a variable to use later in your template I suggest to use just the variable's name `<cfset siteID = ...` without the prefix (scope) when creating.

If you're trying to create a structure with a key `siteID`, I suggest to use something else, more descriptive, to name the structure, not `variable`.

Comment: Downvoted because it's a repeat of the first sentence of Miguel's answer.